# Android App is not listed as tablet capable although it supports large and xlarge screens and screenshots are available

Tags: android, google-play, tablet, android-screen-support

I plan to publish an Android App in the Google Play Store. I uploaded screenshots of 7'' and 10'' tablets and listed large and xlarge support in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Why is it not listed as table capable?

**Addendum**

The play store states: "compatible with all your devices". I own a tablet which is known to the play store. On the other hand "Designed for phones" is shown.

Comment: You might have some permissions which are only tablet compatible ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant phone compatible. Something like Umitik below mentioned.

Comment: I just added the following permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: Might be density-related?
Try adding ' android:anyDensity="true" ' to "supports-screens".

As a last resort you can always manually add devices in the Playstore, but that's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a feature like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

where some tablets do not have calling function. Since you do not declare:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
```

as well to enable manifest that uses call but not required, then app will go for tablets. Same goes for other similar features. Check this for features: [Android-Features](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

Comment: I just added the following permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Then try to add these futures which internet usually use: <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />